# Best approach to backuping program config files?

Tags: backup, configuration

I have a program which looks for a config.json file where it reads needed sensitive infos like DB creds, different APIs creds, etc. I don't upload the config file to the git repository because I understand it's a bad approach, although it's a private repository. Now I'm starting to fear the case that I by accident delete this file, or due to a failure in my machine, I could permanently lose it. My question is - what is the best approach I could use to have a constant secured backup for this file, considering that it may contain very sensitive informations?

Also I would like to specify that this config file is frequently changed (and may increase in size...).

Answer (score 2):

Select, implement, and test a backup system that meets your requirements for securing sensitive data. Access controls to the backup system, encrypting backup media, and logging jobs run are fundamental features to manage data.

Storing secrets in version control like git is tempting. But beware, a git repo may be cloned to many places, and every copy contains your credentials forever.  Deleting them permanently requires rewriting history. Possibly easier to change any creds that got committed, leave the old ones in history, and don't commit secrets in the future.

Think about how you want to manage secrets. Secrets management software exists that wraps creds and keys in strong authentication and encryption. Building the application server could involve installing the application, and retrieving the API creds via the secret server. It may suit your needs to have different systems to store automation scripts, secrets, and backups.

Comment: I thought about just having the config data in a DB table, except for the DB connection creds which needs to be in a local file / env variables. Would that be a good solution?

Comment: I would upvote this answer twice if I could.

Comment: As I said, think about how you manage secrets. If a copy ends up in a local config file that should be secured. Or, perhaps the secret could be retrieved in some script and passed to the app via env var or something, not saved to the application server's disk.